# Need a better EF FindAll() Repository Method

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I inherited a Generic Repository Pattern from the previous developer. It seems to work OK except that I want the FindAll() method to be able to include navigation properties for more then just the first level.

The signature looks like this:

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(List<string> includes, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, IEnumerable<Sorting> orderBy)
```

The includes property lets me pass in the navigation properties I want it to load but ONLY for the top level repository object. Passing in the name of a navigation property for child navigation property of the first level has no effect.

Here is the complete method:

```
        public IEnumerable<T> FindAll(List<string> includes, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where, IEnumerable<Sorting> orderBy)
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _dbSet;
        if (includes != null)
            query = includes.Aggregate(query, (current, include) => current.Include(include));
        if (where != null)
            query = (DbQuery<T>)query.Where(where);
        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            var first = true;

            foreach (var item in orderBy)
            {
                var propertyName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Field) ? string.Empty : item.Field.Trim();
                var dir = string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Dir) ? string.Empty : item.Dir.Trim();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propertyName))
                    throw new ArgumentException("Invalid Property. Order By Format: Property, Property2 ASC, Property2 DESC");

                var descending = false;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dir))
                    descending = dir.Equals("desc", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                if (first)
                    query = descending ? query.OrderByDescending(propertyName) : query.OrderBy(propertyName);
                else
                    query = descending ? query.ThenByDescending(propertyName) : query.ThenBy(propertyName);
                first = false;
            }
        }
        return query;
    }
```

Also, if there is a better method entirely, then please share that with me.

Thank you for your help.

Earl

Comment: Why did you try to pass as `includes` and did not work?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the same method you have.

Just include the name of the second level property in the `Include` string, like this:

```
"FirstLevelProperty.SecondLevelProperty"
```

Comment: Glad this helped! Don't forget to mark this as the answer when you get the chance.